# how to decode a encoded xml in developer studio/ web service

Tags: web-services, soapui, wso2-integration-studio

I am using web services to read a xml report from oracle xmlserver.
The service then returns encoded value of the report and then I have to decode it via web link. Problem is i can not use web link every time to decode it
Is there any way that it doesn't return me encoded value and returns actual xml.
Also, is there any way to decode the encoded file via developer studio?
Any ideas and thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: The above is not clear. Would you mind showing more details ?

Comment: There is a oracle web service to obtain output of report from bi publisher but after reading output it encodes it. I am trying to find a way to decode it via eclipse developer studio